# Android - Drag and drop functionality on images in horizontalScrollView

Tags: android, image, drag-and-drop

I have following UI structure

```
<FrameLayout
<HorizontalScrollView
     <LinearLayout
         <ImageView1  />
          <ImageView2   />
        ........................
          <ImageView7  />
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
<ImageView /></FrameLayout>
```

Now I want to implement drag and drop functionality on  multiple images in linear layout.I have tried lots of code but image is dragged only vertically.I want to drag and drop image anywhere on screen.Please get me out of this trouble.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please visit androidapplicationdeveloper.weebly.com

Comment: Check OpenSource u'll get it.... i had used one far back